# getBoundingClientRect is inaccurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, getboundingclientrect

My goal is to inject an element right before it's on the viewport (depending on the lazy data attribute, default is 100px before the element is on the viewport). And how I do it is by using `getBoundingClientRect();`

```
const LAZY_THRESHOLD_DEFAULT = 100;
TestBox.isOnScreen = function(element) {
    const reservedDistance = parseInt(element.getAttribute(THRESHOLD) || LAZY_THRESHOLD_DEFAULT, 10);
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= $(window).height() &&
        rect.right <= $(window).width()
}
```

And I use it like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (TestBox.isOnScreen(element)) {
    // Inject the element
  }
});
```

One major thing I find out is (I console log the `$(window).scrollTop()` together with console log when `TestBox.isOnScreen(element)`: The moment when the element is detected to be on the viewport is not always accurate. Sometimes by 14px, 5px or exactly good.

Does anyone ever experience this issue? Or am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't be inaccurate, something else is probably going on. Try to see if it's margin, padding or some other style that is interfering. Also, there is no `el` defined in your code, where is that element coming from?

Comment: the problem is there are many elements on the viewports already so it's really hard to figure which margin/padding causes this :(. `el` is the element on the page which I want to be lazy loaded.

Comment: Are you trying this in a mobile browser and, if so, which browser are you using? If it's Edge or Chrome, getBoundingClientRect doesn't return results relative to the "visual viewport" (i.e. window.scrollX|Y, window.innerWidth|Height). It returns results relative to the "layout viewport". See bokan.ca/viewport/index.html for an explanation of the two viewports.